# text area output format

Tags: php, html

When im using text area the output format is different from input format
eg:

input as :

hi,

hello world.

it outputs :

hi,hello world

what changes i want to make this code  to get a format as input.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="textarea.php">
<pre>
<textarea name="name"> </textarea>
</pre>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    echo $name; 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: use `nl2br` to get that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need [`nl2br`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in your PHP.

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    echo nl2br($name); 
}
```

Also, as Quentin mentioned, you really should not be echoing user input back onto a form because that is ripe for XSS disaster, so I hope this is just an exercise for you.

Comment: hm im a rookie on php i dont know there is kind of issues in php i try to learn & i try to level it right..